# Визуализация сортировки по шагам

Tags: c++, сортировка

Я делаю визуализатор сортировки на c++, можно ли используя обычные алгоритмы сортировки пошагово отсортировать массив, т.е. после одного шага прорисовывается один кадр.

Comment: Что значит "обычные алгоритмы сортировки"? Если вы про стандартную библиотеку - нет, нельзя. Если вы про свою реализацию каких-то алгоритмов, то можно, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

Берите код любого алгоритма сортировки и после каждого обмена значений рисуйте состояние (с паузой и подсветкой обменяшихся элементов, если вам нужно).

Comment: Спасибо конечно, я просто думал можно нативными инструментами `stl`

Comment: @Duoxx STL такого точно не предоставляет, т.к. любая сортировка заточена в первую очередь на производительность, а не на вызов колбэков каждый шаг.